# jquery div positioned next to mouse moves depending on browser window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

The hidden div shows itself when user hovers over area on mapped image. But I need the hidden div to be positioned next to the mouse. It currently positions itself some distance from the mouse and this distance varies depending on the size of the browser window.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hover_link").mousemove(function(e){         
        $("#box1").show();         
        $(".box").css({             
            top: (e.pageY - 240) + "px",             
            left: (e.pageX - 90) + "px"        
        });    
    });     
    $(".hover_link").mouseout(function(e){         
        $("#box1").hide();     
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.hover_link{
    display:block;
}
.box{
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    display:none;
    height: 80px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 0;
    }
    .boxinner{
    text-align:left;
    max-width:140px;
    padding-left:10px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.poltairhomes.com/images/swmap.jpg" width="900" height="642" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area class="hover_link" shape="circle" coords="574,143,10" href="http://www.poltairhomes.com/trecerus-farm" />
</map>
<div class="box" id="box1" align="center">
    <div class="boxinner">
        <img src="http://www.poltairhomes.com/images/homethumb1.png" width="80px" height="80px" />
    </div>
    <div class="boxinner">Trecerus Farm Development: 22 Two, Three &amp; Four bed homes.
    </div>
</div>
```

Website: http://www.poltairhomes.com/developments/

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I've now updated my jquery to the following, but now the hidden div doesn't display at all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hover_link").mousemove(function(e){         
        $("#box1").show();         
        $(".box").css({             
            top: ((e.pageY - $("#main").offest().left) + 10) + "px",             
            left: ((e.pageX - $("#main").offset().top) + 10) + "px"        
        });    
    });     
    $(".hover_link").mouseout(function(e){         
        $("#box1").hide();     
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2:** jquery is now as follows, but again, the hidden div doesn't appear to reveal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hover_link").mousemove(function(e){         
        $("#box1").show();
            var main = $("#main");
            var offset = main.offset();
            var mouseY = (e.pageY - main.offset.left); 
            var mouseX = (e.pageX - main.offset.top);        
            $(".box").css({             
                top: (mouseY + 10) + "px",             
                left: (mouseX + 10) + "px"        
            });    
        });     
    $(".hover_link").mouseout(function(e){         
        $("#box1").hide();     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So! In the end the problem was that I had the jquery running on a div that was within a centred fixed width div on the page.

To get around this I basically detected the html document width, subtracted the fixed width of the div, then divided the remainder by two, giving me the left margin that I needed to offset my mouse calculation by in order to get the hidden div to pop up next to the mouse no matter what the window size was.

The header of the site is also a fixed size, so I subtracted it's height from my mouse position to get the hidden to div to position correctly on the other axis.

Final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kWq7/10/
Final result: http://jsfiddle.net/3kWq7/10/embedded/result/
Final jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hover_link").mousemove(function(e){         
        $($(this).attr('rel')).show();
        var padding = parseInt(jQuery("#page").css("margin-right"));
        var margin = $(document).width() - 900;
        var marginleft = margin / 2;        
            $(".box").css({             
            top: (e.pageY - 200) + "px",             
            left: (e.pageX - marginleft + 10) + "px"        
        });    
    });     
    $(".hover_link").mouseout(function(e){         
        $($(this).attr('rel')).hide();   
    });
});
```

Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 1):

When you set *top* and *left* properties to an element that has *position:absolute*, those values are distances from the first parent element that has *position:relative*.

Your CSS for *.singular .hentry* sets *position:relative* to the article element inside which your div is. So when you set *top:50px*, it means it should be 50px from the top of that article element, not 50px from the top of the page.

Either remove the *position:relative* from the article element or calculate the coordinates for the div so that they are relative to the article element and not the entire page.

EDIT: Also, you shouldn't subtract the dimensions of the div from the *e.pageX* and *e.pageY*. The *top* and *left* values specify where the upper left corner of your div will start. You can add 5px to both values to make it appear right next to the cursor.

EDIT2: This is working for me:

```
$(".hover_link").mouseover(function(e) {
    $("#box1").show();
    var offset = $('#mapwrapper').offset();
    $(".box").css({
      top: (e.pageY - offset.top + 10) + "px",
      left: (e.pageX - offset.left + 10) + "px"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mzgajner, I've removed "position:relative" from ".singular .hentry" but it still moves the hidden div to right dependant on the overall window size?

Comment: I've changed the jquery to +5px instead of subtracting. In doing so it has highlighted just how far out the positioning is! Any help would be **greatly** appreciated... Thanks

Comment: Thanks @mzgajner - it works for me too on the Fiddle, but not on the site... can't for the life of me work out why? http://www.polatirhomes.com/developments

Comment: Are you sure @bigtoothmedia? I saved your site to my hard drive and just replaced the function in the script file with mine and it worked for me.

Comment: I worked out how to get it working (answer below). Not sure why it didn't work with your solution - I tried all sorts of variations based on the same theme you explored with offset and/ or position but no joy... Thanks for you input though :)